# ssrs reporting report with addition RowNumber function

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to make report table in ssrs like this

```
row  D/C          nominal saldo

1   Credit        10      10
2   Debet         1       9 (from 10-1)
3   Credit        6       15 (from 9+6)
```

How to make function "saldo" field as above?

```
the logical flow
when row number = 1 then saldo = nominal (just for first row).  
when row number = 2 and  D/C = Debit then "saldo" row 1 - nominal  
when row number = 2 and  D/C = Credit then "saldo" row 1 + nominal  
when row number = 3 and  D/C = Debit then "saldo" row 2 - nominal  
when row number = 3 and  D/C = Credit then "saldo" row 2 + nominal
```

I'm trying to use function RowNumber (Nothing),

```
Iif(RowNumber(nothing)=1,Fields!nominal.Value),
Iif(RowNumber(nothing)=2 and Fields!dc.Value = "Debit",previousFields!saldo.Value - Fields!nominal.Value ),
```

and so on..

Could you give me suggestion about that scribs?

Regardz
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a running total. Assuming your number are all positive then just check the debit/credit column and multiply the value by -1 when required.

Something like this should work.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!nomial.Value * (IIF(Fields!dc.Value="Debit",-1,1) ,Sum,”yourDataSetName”)
```

If you really want the row number as well then you can just add a column with the expression set to `=RowNumber(nothing)`

Comment: I got  "#Error". I tried to convert with "CDbl" but still #Error